# What is the difference between "tithe" and "tenth"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

Is it correct to use the term *tenth* with the sense of *tithe* (payments to the church)?

What are the differences between the two terms? Is the first one more generally while the second one is specific to the church tithe payments?

Are there any other related terms which I can use instead of *tithe*, but with the same meaning?

Can *tenth* replace *tithe* in the church payments context (e.g. *I payed the tenth to the church I belong to*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **tithe** was originally a donation or payment which was a tenth of something, usually a person's income. But these days it is frequently used without a precise numerical value to mean a donation to a church.

Your question isn't clear about what context you want to use alternative words, but *donation*, *gift* or *contribution* are options, and if it's in a religious context then *offering* is common too.

It would be inappropriate to simply replace *tithe* with *tenth* because *tenth* is not used as a noun in English now, only as a quantifier. If you say 'a tenth' you need to specify 'of something'.

Comment: If the OP is thinking of using "tithe" in a non-ecclesiastical context, then the word is "don't". If he wants synonyms, Curious has given some.

Comment: *It would be inappropriate to simply replace tithe with tenth because tenth is not used as a noun in English now, only as a quantifier* - OK, that's what it was unclear to me. Thanks! In our language (Romanian), they are the same word which translated means *tenth*.